# what is the alternative of log4j methods in log4j2

Tags: java, spring

In my old code(which is in log4j), we are using

```
 private void hello(LoggingEvent event)
    {
      String[] eventStackTrace = event.getThrowableStrRep();
      
   }
```

Now we have to change our code to log4j2.

For the Event, we are using the format method

```
public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder outputMessage) 
{
        
}
```

How we can get the getThrowableStrRep value in log4j2.

Comment: It seems like your question is more related to log4j/log4j2 than to spring. It would help if you could reference what class LogEvent actually is.

Comment: That is LogEventPatternConverter class method.

Comment: I'm afraid I am unable to help. I do not know LogEventPattenConverter.